# a challenge for google recaptcha v3

Tags: javascript, recaptcha-v3

I wanted to add google recaptcha to my sign up page on my web site.
I decided to use google recaptcha v3 https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

I implemented it on my website and sometimes when users sign up, the score from recaptcha it low and it is suggested to show a challenge, but from what I understood from google recaptcha v3 documentation, there is no challenge in recaptcha v3, I need to take actions into my own hands.
the problem is that I have no idea what else to do besides showing a challenge to the user.

so.. there are two options:

1. I misread the documentation and there is a way to show a google recaptcha v3 challenge, in this case... what do I do ?
2. I should downgrade to google recaptcha v2 since it has a challenge in it's api.

I know that you guys hate questions without pasting code but there isn't really anything to paste here besides the basic implementation of google recaptcha that is just presented in the url I provided in the beginning of this post.

so how do I handle users having low score?

any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a reason why you can't use both versions (2 & 3), just create a new key for recaptcha v2 - You can use them both on the same website for this type of scenario

Comment: _" a registration page might still use reCAPTCHA v2 for a higher-friction challenge, whereas more common actions like sign-in, searches, comments, or voting might use reCAPTCHA v3"_ ([Can I run reCAPTCHA v2 and v3 on the same page?](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-run-recaptcha-v2-and-v3-on-the-same-page))